Have the authors appropriately applied repeated measures one way ANOVA and ROC analysis in this test of therapist adherence?
I'm reading a piece of research about the type of psychotherapy I practice. My intuition is that the use of statistics in the paper is flawed, but I am ideologically motivated to find flaws in this particular piece of research and my knowledge of statistics is fairly basic. For these reasons, I won't link to the paper.
All the authors of the paper are psychotherapists trained in the same type of therapy. They created a questionnaire to be used by an observer trained in that therapy to rate the degree to which a therapist worked within that therapy in a given session. (i.e. It is a test of adherence.) The authors distributed this questionnaire to about 200 participants (all trained in the therapy of interest) along with videos of 4 therapy sessions; 2 by therapists trained in the therapy of interest and 2 by therapists trained in another therapy. Participants scored the first two videos more highly (each approx. mean = 16.5, sd = 0.2) than the second two videos (each approx. mean = 4.5, sd = 0.25), indicating that use of the questionnaire was clearly distinguishing between therapy delivered by people trained in the therapy of interest and therapy delivered by people trained in the other therapy.
The authors presented the mean and sd values above as part of a "one way repeated measures ANOVA" test, which they said demonstrated statistical significance.
They then performed a ROC analysis to determine the threshold score that divided the therapy of interest from other types of therapy and got a value of 11.
I have two concerns:
1: Statology says that, "A repeated measures one-way ANOVA is used to determine whether or not there is a statistically significant difference between the means of three or more groups in which the same subjects show up in each group." I can see how there could be 4 groups here (1 group of scores for each of the 4 videos) but, taking Statology's wording literally, that would mean that the observer-raters are the subjects rather than the videoed sessions that they are rating. If the purpose of the research is to find a way to distinguish between the therapy of interest and other types of therapy then surely what we actually have is two groups (2 samples of the therapy of interest and 2 from another therapy.) If we only have 4 samples then I assume that tests of statistical significance are not yet appropriate. I am open to being told that I'm thinking about this incorrectly and would welcome any comments.
2: Wikipedia says that ROC analysis was developed in order to determine what strength of signal should be considered an object worth displaying on radar. I assume that task is necessarily binary in order to limit the amount of information that a radar operator has to parse. I don't see the applicability of a threshold to a scale to determine whether someone is adhering to a particular kind of therapy (especially if we only have 4 samples and we've only rated 2 types of therapy.) Again, I would welcome any comments, including any corrections of my perspective.
I don't know enough to determine whether I've posted enough information regarding the study. Please say if I should give more details.
Edit: The answer I will probably accept answers this question that I put in one of my comments...

How many videos would we need to have rated in order to be confident that we have developed a tool that can distinguish between the therapy of interest and any other therapy?


I’m not sure about the ROC analysis here since it’s unclear if the intent of the questionnaire was to “detect” which therapy was being conducted. What were they rating? The quality of the therapy? Whether it adhered to the standards of their pet therapy? It’s defensible in the second case but not really the first. Not sure what it really adds here.

It seems to me that a couple of study design considerations are missing. If all of the participants are trained in this therapeutic modality, who (or what) acts as the control group? Next, is the design blind to participants? Iow, how informed are they to the study's objectives?

@RickHass The questionnaire was designed to detect whether the therapy of interest was being adhered to. (When testing the efficacy of a given therapy against wait-list-controls in an RCT you are generally expected to test therapist adherence to that therapy.)

@user78229 If I understand correctly then the participants knew what the purpose of the study was. I don't understand what a control group would accomplish in this study. (Anyone using the questionnaire in the future would probably be trained in the therapy of interest.)


How many videos would we need to have rated in order to be confident that we have developed a tool that can distinguish between the therapy of interest and any other therapy?

This is a question of statistical power. We can answer it — approximately — by running simulations, under reasonable assumptions about the data generating process (DGP), the experimental design and the statistical model.
I agree with the OP that with 200 participants each judging all 4 videos, the study has a lot of power to detect differences between those 4 videos but (likely) not enough power to say much in general about the therapy of interest and any other therapy. The challenge is how much variability we expect between trained therapists and between sessions.
Obviously, filming a therapy session is a lot more work than distributing questionnaires which is why the study has 4 videos of therapy sessions and 200 participants filling a questionnaire. However, intuitively the experiment will have more power to detect differences between therapies with more videos (of randomly selected therapists / sessions) than with more participants scoring only a few videos.
Note: I interpret "trained in the therapy of interest" and "trained in another therapy" to mean there are two therapies in this investigation, A (therapy of interest) and B (another kind of therapy that is commonly used ie. the "control" therapy). However, the statement is also consistent with three therapies: the therapy A and two alternative therapies B and C. Either way, can we take one or two therapies to represent "any other therapy"? I suppose it depends on what the available therapies are.
I don't have the domain knowledge necessary to simulate credible data for this problem. Nevertheless, I generate some normal data under specific assumptions about the therapy effect & the variability between sessions and between participants, in order to estimate the power to detect the therapy effect with two different models: one model with sessions as fixed effects (as in the paper) and another model with sessions as random effects.
M1:  Y ~ session + (1 | subject)
M2:  Y ~ therapy + (1 | session) + (1 | subject)

Notice that M1 doesn't have an explicit therapy parameter. I suspect the authors resort to a ROC analysis of the "therapy threshold" to deal with this particular difficulty. Since I don't understand how they to do ROC analysis, I take advantage of the fact that there are two sessions under each therapy and use a contrast to estimate the therapy effect under M1:
(b_session3 + b_session4) / 2 - (b_session1 + b_session2) / 2

Under M2 the therapy effect is simply b_therapy2. (The bs stand for fixed-effect parameters.)
To estimate the power to detect a non-zero therapy effect, I simulate data 100 times and keep track the p-values for the null hypothesis of no therapy effect under models M1 and M2. Assuming that we choose the conventional significance level, ɑ = 0.05, the estimated power is the proportion p < ɑ. I attach the full R code at the end but keep in mind that I don't attempt to choose DGP settings so that the simulations are consistent with the numbers reported in the question. I only want to make a point that — with the same experimental data — we get very different power to detect a "therapy effect" depending on the model we use. That's because under M1 the therapy effect is specific to the 4 filmed sessions while M2 makes a claim about the average therapy effect across the distribution of sessions.
# Settings to describe the experimental design.
n_subject <- 200
n_therapy <- 2
n_session_per_therapy <- 2
n_session_per_subject <- 4

# Are these parameter values realistic? Probably not.
therapy_effect <- 10
sigma_session <- 3
sigma_subject <- 3
sigma <- 1 # residual std. error

Estimated power under the two models:
alpha <- 0.05
mean(p_under_M1 < alpha)
#> [1] 0.94
mean(p_under_M2 < alpha)
#> [1] 0.49

With M1, we test the null hypothesis of no therapy effect in the specific 4 therapy session; we have a lot of power for this analysis (due to the within-participant design, ie. due to the fact that every participant judges every session). With M2, we test the null hypothesis of no therapy effect overall; we have a lot less power for this analysis (and the way to increase the power is to film more sessions).
PS. I'm not convinced by the stated reason for not citing the original paper in question. It hardly seems more even-handed to only present one's own reading of their analysis & arguments. This way we cannot judge for example whether the authors extrapolated from their 4 videos to make claims about therapy sessions in general.

library("multcomp") # To compute the contrast (session4 + session3)/2 - (session1 + session2)/2
library("lmerTest") # To compute p-values for fixed effects in an lmer model.
library("lme4")
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1234)

# Settings to describe the experimental design.
n_subject <- 200
n_therapy <- 2
n_session_per_therapy <- 2
n_session_per_subject <- 4

# Are these parameter values realistic? Probably not.
therapy_effect <- 10
sigma_session <- 3
sigma_subject <- 3
sigma <- 1 # residual std. error

# Set up the data frame that represents the experimental design.
# This is a very simple simulation. We need to choose the sizes, so that
# (n_subject * n_session_per_subject) / (n_therapy * n_session_per_therapy) is an integer.
dat <-
  tibble(
    subject = rep(1:n_subject, each = n_session_per_subject),
    therapy = rep(1:n_therapy, times = (n_subject * n_session_per_subject) / n_therapy),
    session = rep(1:(n_therapy * n_session_per_therapy), times = (n_subject * n_session_per_subject) / (n_therapy * n_session_per_therapy))
  ) |>
  mutate(
    subject = factor(paste0("S", subject)),
    therapy = factor(paste0("T", therapy)),
    session = factor(paste0("S", session))
  )

p_under_M1 <- numeric(100)
p_under_M2 <- numeric(100)

for (i in 1:100) {
  dat$y <- simulate(
    ~ therapy + (1 | session) + (1 | subject),
    newdata = dat,
    newparams = list(
      beta = sigma * c(
        `(Intercept)` = 0,
        `therapyT2` = therapy_effect
      ),
      theta = c(
        `session.(Intercept)` = sigma_session / sigma,
        `subject.(Intercept)` = sigma_subject / sigma
      ),
      sigma = sigma
    )
  )[[1]]
  
  M1 <- lmer(
    y ~ session + (1 | subject),
    data = dat
  )
  M2 <- lmer(
    y ~ therapy + (1 | session) + (1 | subject),
    data = dat
  )
  
  # This contrast only makes sense with 4 sessions, two from each therapy.
  contrast <- glht(M1, linfct = mcp(session = "(S3 + S4)/2 - (S1 + S2)/2 = 0"))
  
  p_under_M1[i] <- as.numeric(summary(contrast)$test$pvalues)
  p_under_M2[i] <- as.numeric(coef(summary(M2))[2, 5])
}

alpha <- 0.05
mean(p_under_M1 < alpha)
mean(p_under_M2 < alpha)


Thank you for this. I'm going to have to do some research to understand understand all the concepts you touch upon but I am okay with that. You are correct, of course, that I can't even-handedly present contents of the paper myself. My reflex to not make waves is counter-productive here. I need to think about that and talk to a supervisor about it.

P.S. You were correct that the 4 videos were of just two types of therapy (two of the therapy of interest and two of a very different type of therapy.) If you think I should edit the original question to make this clear then I can do that, although I'm aware you've answered the question as it is currently stated.

Hello. I might have been too inflexible re: the citation, sorry about that. I'd say that the fact that there's one alternative therapy is less interesting than the fact that it's known that this other therapy is very different. Doesn't this mean that testing $H_0: therapy = 0$ is "not interesting"?

Overall I'm still not sure what the purpose of the paper is. Perhaps it was mainly about the questionnaire design? If I venture a guess that the questionnaire has 20 yes/no questions and the therapy of interest tends to get 16.5 yes's, then isn't it more interesting why there's a gap of 3.5 "adherence points" on average? Anyway, I expect there are various meaningful scientific questions that can be asked & they can't all be answered with the same experimental design & statistical analysis.

For historical and ideological reasons, there is a lot of research on the efficacy of individual psychotherapies, even though the preponderance of research shows that there is very little difference in efficacy between them (once you control for researcher allegiance effects.) In order to carry out that research, you have to show that your participating therapists are actually "doing" your therapy, hence you need a measure of adherence,  hence this study to develop such a measure for one therapy.
